# How can I import odeint and arange in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, python-import, importerror

I am trying to import odeint in python by doing:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
```

but there is an error note:

ImportError: No module named scipy.integrate

I have looked through some websites and there is a module called scipy.integrate, I am not sure what is going wrong with my code?

I also tried

```
from scipy import arange
```

which also shows similar error message:

ImportError: No module named scipy

I am using Python 2.7.8. Is it due to the version of Python? How can I fix it then?

If I could not even import them, I won't be able to continue writing my code.

Could somebody please give some advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, have you *installed* `scipy`? In the same interpreter/environment? It's not included in the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when `scipy` is not installed.

Download & Install SciPy from : [Scientific Python](https://www.scipy.org/install.html)

Ubuntu & Debian : `sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose`

Fedora: `sudo yum install numpy scipy python-matplotlib ipython python-pandas sympy python-nose`

Windows : [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

[SciPy source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases)